# WPF MediaElement play http url and storage problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a MediaElement playing a google drive link like so
xaml code:

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="MdPlayer"
               MaxHeight="350"
               MaxWidth="350"                                  
               Margin="5">
 </MediaElement>
```

.cs code:

```
MdPlyr.Source = new Uri(@"http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1jWhVXnC9ziy5jNZeDpcJpTUGrAcF4fNf");// It's actually runbable
```

When I access to the link on web browser, it download the file, while playing it with MediaElement I didn't have to download it at all. I wonder if the file is downloaded and stored somewhere in the background or is it streamed directly on google drive. Is there any keyword so that I can look into this kind of things?

Comment: Mediaelement is just a wrapper around media player. That caches files in a similar manner to web browsers.

Comment: @Andy So is this cache files increased and stored permanently somewhere in the computer, let say I play a 3GB video file. If so, is there any ways to optimize the storage, delete the cache at the completion of the video or when turn off app?

Comment: It is media player. https://www.sorcim.com/blog/windows-11-media-player-cache-cleaning-deduplication